# 3D Plot in Matlab - not correct

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the potential function in a given coplanar rectangular structure. Here is the equation i deduced by using mathematics, here is the sumary:
[Assumption](http://www.flickr.com/photos/79968668@N08/11068870295/)

Now I try to plot it in MATLAB, here is my code:

```
function [x,y,v] = potentialFM(a1,a2,a3,b)
syms n;

%range in normalized values
x=0:1/20:1;
y=0:(b/a3)/20:(b/a3);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

%normalized values
an1=a1/a3;
an2=a2/a3;
bn=b/a3;

%symbol k 
k=(n.*2+1)*(pi/2);

C1=(1/(k.^2)).*(2/(an1-an2));
C2=cos(k.*an2)-cos(k.*an1);
C3=1/(sinh(k.*bn));
Vx=cos(X*k);
Vy=sinh(Y*k);
v=symsum(C1.*C2.*C3.*Vx.*Vy,n,1,20);
end
```

So, Could someone have a try to my code and check where is an error. The result should look like the assumed graph in the link but i cannot achieve it.

Best Regards,

fRz

Comment: There is one error; according to the linked image it should be `k=(n.*2+1)*pi/2`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a problem with plotting, but with the evaluation of your function. Why do you use symbolics if you want a numeric result ready for plotting?

Here's a simple fix – `n` is now simply a loop variable, `k` another normal variable, and the sum is computed cumulatively using the variable `v`:

```
function [x,y,v] = potentialFM(a1,a2,a3,b)

%range in normalized values
x=0:1/20:1;
y=0:(b/a3)/20:(b/a3);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

%normalized values
an1=a1/a3;
an2=a2/a3;
bn=b/a3;

v = 0;
for n = 1 : 20
    k=(n.*2+1)*(pi/2);

    C1=(1/(k.^2)).*(2/(an1-an2));
    C2=cos(k.*an2)-cos(k.*an1);
    C3=1/(sinh(k.*bn));
    Vx=cos(X*k);
    Vy=sinh(Y*k);
    v = v + C1.*C2.*C3.*Vx.*Vy;
end
```

This is not necessarily the most efficient implementation, maybe some of the computations could be vectorized – but it works. Choosing arbitrarily the parameters,

```
[x,y,v] = potentialFM(1, 2, 3, 4);
surf(x, y, v)
```

gives:

[image: surface plot]

Comment: Hi A. Donda, 
Thank you for your reply. I am not good at MATLAB, during trying to make a infinite sum, i found command "symsum" which uses symbolized computation. Therefore i assign the symbols here. In my case, to plot the result, i also used "surf" command, like this:
surf(x,y,double(v));
it give the same result (plot) like your program, but much more slower. 
However, my main question is that the plot seems to be not as similar as i expected (which is in the assumption link i attached). Therefore, i wonder there are some mistakes here.
Best regards,
fRz

Comment: @user3036972: So my solution doesn't help you because you need the infinite sum? Well, I don't have much experience with the symbolic math toolbox, but the result you function gives in the original form involves complicated expressions, and my impression is that they only get more complicated for higher upper limit of `n`. Are you sure your series has a closed form solution?

Comment: If the series converges reasonably fast, I'd still recommend to use my numerical version, and set the upper limit to a value where the sum doesn't change much anymore. After all, most numerics works by finding sufficiently good approximations, and for a plot you don't need a precision of more than about three decimals.

Comment: I just tested, and for the parameter values chosen by me I get divergent results for larger upper limit – which suggests that there is no closed form. Which parameter values are you interested in?

Comment: in theoretical point of view, it requires infinite sum. But my task is to deduce equivalent function and also to find some reasonable limit (in my code, i try to sum up the fourier series just until 10), as you said. Sorry for my misunderstanding, what do you mean "closed form solution"? - do you mean the Convergence of my equation?

Comment: "Closed form" means a formula that gives the value of the infinite sum directly, without writing it as an infinite sum. – As I said, as long as the sum converges, the standard way to numerically treat it is to sum up to a finite order. But if you ultimately don't want to evaluate or plot, I think using a tool that is more specialized to symbolic work makes more sense, i.e. Mathematica. For this you also don't need to mix in numerics, fixing special values for x and y using meshgrid – if the sum is defined, there should be a general formula that works for arbitrary values of x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt: If you need the value of the infinite sum and hope that `symsum` can find a closed form expression, there is no need to mix it with numerics. Instead, declare all the variables as symbolic:

```
syms n an1 an2 bn X Y
k=(n.*2+1)*(pi/2);
C1=(1/(k.^2)).*(2/(an1-an2));
C2=cos(k.*an2)-cos(k.*an1);
C3=1/(sinh(k.*bn));
Vx=cos(X*k);
Vy=sinh(Y*k);
v=symsum(C1.*C2.*C3.*Vx.*Vy,n,1,inf);
```

`symsum` returns a result, but it looks like this:

```
-(8*sum(((exp(-(pi*X*(2*n + 1)*i)/2)/2 + exp((pi*X*(2*n + 1)*i)/2)/2)*(exp(-(pi*Y*(2*n + 1))/2)/2 - exp((pi*Y*(2*n + 1))/2)/2)*(exp(-(pi*an1*(2*n + 1)*i)/2)/2 + exp((pi*an1*(2*n + 1)*i)/2)/2 - exp(-(pi*an2*(2*n + 1)*i)/2)/2 - exp((pi*an2*(2*n + 1)*i)/2)/2))/((2*n + 1)^2*(exp(-(pi*bn*(2*n + 1))/2)/2 - exp((pi*bn*(2*n + 1))/2)/2)), n == 1..Inf))/(pi^2*(an1 - an2))
```

As you can see, the *Symbolic Math Toolbox* was able to perform some simplifications (?) but could not solve the core of the problem: There is still an infinite sum in there. As far as I understand, this indicates that there is no closed form expression (or at least that finding it is beyond the capabilities of the toolbox).

Comment: Dear @Donda, i appreciate for your supports. I think there is some misunderstand in here. May i ask you a question, did you have a look on my assumption (the link i attached). The solution is in the Fourier series, it means there should be infinite sum here. But as we know, infinite sum is not necessary (just in theory). therefore, i just try to find "accepted" upper limit. The thing is, when i deduce Fourier Series for my equation base from the assumption, when i reconstruct my equation (by plotting), i expected the plot somehow similar to the grahp of the orignal function.

Comment: But, i got no success about the result of plotting. I am not familiar with MATLAB, so i do not know whether my deduced function is wrong or my code is wrong. :). I don't think there was a mistake in my function :)

Comment: Yes I had a look, but I'm afraid I don't really understand the point of it just from that part. For starters, the function shown there has only one argument, x, not two. I also don't see why the Fourier series of such a simple  stepwise linear function would involve a sinus hyperbolicus.

Comment: I have the feeling your problem is not really implementation in Matlab, but understanding what needs to be implemented. I could try to help with that, but a) I think that belongs on math.stackexchange.com, and b) there needs to be more context: What is a coplanar structure, what has it to do with this function, why is its Fourier series interesting, ...

Comment: :).I am doing analysis in field distribution (electrical + magnetic) in the pcb board. coplanar structure is a structure of the pcb board. To find field distribution, i need find potential function. Certainly it depends on x,y variables. and in general, base on laplace equation+ boundary condition, the function of potential function would have the form: SUM(An * cos(kx)*sinh(ky)), k is (2n+1)*pi/2 in this case. To find coefficients An, i need to apply the assumption which mentioned in the script. please be careful, this is the assumption with condition V(x, y=b=const), so it depends only on x

Comment: after this step, i know An, which means i can have my final solution for the whole coordinate which depends on both x and y. That's why you see my assumption is only depends on x but the final solution has y-components. I am sorry not to write this one clearly.

Comment: Why don't you make a new question, maybe here or maybe on math.stackexchange.com, where you describe all this context, explain what you are actually trying to achieve, why you went to implement this series in Matlab, and where exatcly you got stuck – everything. I'll guarantee you, there's a much better chance you get help if you do that, from me or from someone else. Also consider asking on electronics.stackexchange.com, where there might be more people who tried to do something similar.